# What is the projected area of a solid onto an axis of rotation?

Tags: geometry

A [thesis](https://ntnuopen.ntnu.no/ntnu-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/238170/566076_FULLTEXT01.pdf) describing the hydrodynamic forces acting on a remotely operated underwater vehicle writes (p. 29),

> In order to [derive] a nonlinear damping matrix, these coefficients have to be multiplied by projected area of the ROV in surge, sway, heave and along the axes of rotation of the ROV.

I understand the projected area along the axes of translation (surge, $X$; sway, $Y$; heave, $Z$). For example, I can orthographically project the solid onto the $XY$ plane and take the area of the 2D "shadow".

I am unsure about how to visualize or compute projected area onto an axis of *rotation*, though.

Comment: Units are meters squared so I think they mean the plane of rotation with the axes as normal. The measure tool in SolidWorks displays both the planar projection and the normal so that may have been what led to the confusion.